# Postman не возвращает данные

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Я хочу получить данные из БД и отобразить их в Postman. В режиме отладки видно, что данные подтягиваются, но в постмене почему-то пусто

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> GetProductComparsionByListId(int listId)
    {
        var comparsionList = _dbContext.ProductsComparsion.Include(z => z.ProductsToCompare).FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == listId);

        if (comparsionList == null)
            return null;

        var category = _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Id == comparsionList.CategoryId);


        var tmp = new ProductComparsionVM
        { 
            // Если оставить эту строку, то ничего не возвращает
            // Если ее закомментить и вернуть любое другое свойство, все работает
            // В обоих случаях Postman отрабатывает с кодом '200 OK'
            ProductsToCompare2 = comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.ToList()
        };

        return tmp;
    }

    public class ProductComparsionVM
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int ListId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public List<int> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }

        public List<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare2 { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductComparsionByListId([FromBody] ProductComparsionVM comparsion)
    {
        return Json(await _productRepo.GetProductComparsionByListId(comparsion.ListId));
    }

public class ProductToCompare
{
    public int ProductComparsionId { get; set; }
    public ProductComparsion ProductComparsion { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: 1) тут на русише пишут 2) добавте в вопрос описание ProductToCompare

Comment: @Vasek Поправил

Comment: Статус код какой? Попробуйте возращать вместо`IActionResult` ваш класс.

Comment: попробуйте пометить listID атрибутом [FromBody], или передавать параметр во вкладке Params, в постмане

Comment: @Vasek Статус '200 OK', если возвращать класс, то результат такой-же

Comment: @Ruslan_K ListId передается. Проблема в том, что именно свойство `ProductsToCompare2` не возвращает. Остальные возвращает, если его закомментить

Comment: Подозреваю что проблема в каком то поле ваших классов ProductToCompare, ProductComparsion, Product. Попробуйте поочередно комментировать у них свойства. Или приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример с вашими классами.